# Mesh isn't found when attatching Camera to it Unreal, C++

Tags: c++, camera, game-engine, unreal-engine4

I'm working un Unreal on C++ and am trying to attatch my CameraBoom as shown below to the character Mesh. I get this error:

USkeletalMeshComponent*ACharacter::Mesh
argument of type "USkeletalMeshComponent*" is incompatible with parameter of type "USceneComponent"

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYuOI9pwiaE&t=1436s and cant see anyone else that is having issue. This is the issue area.

```
void AGroupProjectCharacter::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    CameraBoom->TargetArmLength = 0.0f;

    CameraBoom->AttachTo(Mesh, "customHeadSocket");

    bUseControllerRotationPitch = false;
    bUseControllerRotationYaw = true;
    bUseControllerRotationRoll = true;
}
```

The word "Mesh" is underlined in red. The only solution i could find online was to make sure you include the header file, which is already done. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you #include "Components/SkeletalMeshComponent.h" and try again?

Comment: @BasinhetVeld Thank You! That fixed that issue.